# Where is /sys/bus/usb/devices on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, usb, osx-mountain-lion

I've installed libusb via Homebrew, and trying to compile usbutils, but the utils tell me that **/sys/bus/usb/devices** can not be found. Of course I'm on Mac OS X (Mountain Lion), so I would need to change the path in the source and recompile.

Can anyone help me out as to where the location of /sys/bus/usb/devices is on Mac?

Comment: Nowhere. OS X doesn't use sysfs.

Comment: So that would mean usbutils won't work on Mac, dammit!

Comment: Not unless it's ported to use OS X-specific USB mechanisms.

Comment: I haven't used libusb, but I did try to download it from Macports.  It appears to have downloaded and installed properly.  Try getting it through Macports and see if that helps.

Comment: Libusb is fine, it's the usbutils bit that come in addition to that. It hasn't been developed for Mac, but I've started a small C command line app that will give output enumerated devices and their USB descriptor details.